# What is the correct process for adding/editing rosdep keys?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a documented process?

Is the accepted practice to make pull requests with the changes to the rosdep files here:
https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep

Thanks in advance for any clarifications/info.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189743/what-is-the-correct-process-for-adding/editing-rosdep-keys?/) by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 211 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, changes there should reflect the best knowledge of publicly available packages. If you have more packages you'd like to capture please submit pull requests for the updates.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) on 2014-08-11**:
Thanks Tully! Wanted to confirm that that was the correct way to do things before opening up pulls willy-nilly.